# Cron executing wrong

Tags: linux, cron, cron-task, crontrigger

was set on crontab the line below. But is not validate the day. When I remove de day of week is executed correctly. Any suggestion?

```
# uname -a
Linux server 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jul 16 23:51:20 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# cat /etc/issue
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Kernel \r on an \m

# date
Mon Mar  2 08:50:19 BRT 2015

# crontab -l
* * 1 3 1 echo "teste"

# tail -f /var/log/cron
Mar  2 08:38:01 server CROND[10509]: (root) CMD (echo "teste")
```

Comment: add some meaningful explanation. Currently the only way to understand your problem is by reading the code, whereas I am sure you can explain it yourself. You can also give a read to [Tips for debugging cron issues from crontab wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)

Comment: Thanks. In this link answered my question when said that: "... there is one exception: if both "day of month" and "day of week" are restricted (not "*"), then either the "day of month" field (3) **or** the "day of week" field (5) must match the current day. ..."

Comment: How can I set cron run only: 
Monday 02 of March

Comment: If you want to say `Monday 2 March` you can probably say `* * 2 3 *`. But this work on every 2 March, so also next year, etc.

Comment: But I would like only Monday. For example in next year 2 March is Thursday and didn't can be executed.

Comment: A similar problem is said in [Run a cron job on the first Monday of every month?](http://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month) and [How to run a cron job on the first weekday of the month](http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/) so I tried "* * 1 3 * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Mon" ] && mkdir /tmp/cronsilvioteste" and not runned.

Answer (score 0):

If the time interval can't be defined in crontab, you can use a date/time check in the script itself. You can force crontab to run script at every 2nd March and check inside the script if the day is actually Monday. If not, you can exit the script.

Eg.

```
[[ $( date +%u ) -ne 1 ]] && exit
```

If the day isn't Monday, exit.

Answer (score 0):

[About crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info)
"... there is one exception: if both "day of month" and "day of week" are restricted (not "*"), then either the "day of month" field (3) **or** the "day of week" field (5) must match the current day. ..."

A similar problem is said in [Run a cron job on the first Monday of every month?](https://superuser.com/questions/428807/run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-monday-of-every-month) and [How to run a cron job on the first weekday of the month](http://www.switchplane.com/blog/how-to-run-a-cron-job-on-the-first-weekday-of-the-month/)

So, in crontab set:

* * 1 3 * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Sun" ] && /bin/mkdir /tmp/cronsilvioteste